# echo not returning variable value on php actionscript connection

Tags: php, mysql, flash, actionscript, echo

I'm trying to pass some variables from php to flash, im using this actionscript code:

```
public function gameOver(score:Number) 
{
    totalScore.text = score.toString();

    var scriptVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    scriptVars.score = score;

    var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("checkScores.php");
    scriptRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    scriptRequest.data = scriptVars;

    scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);
    scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadSuccessful);
    scriptLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoadError);
}

function handleLoadSuccessful(e:Event):void
{
    trace("Scores Loaded");
    var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
    nickname1.text = vars.nickname;
    score1.text = vars.score;
}

function handleLoadError($evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("Load failed.");
    nickname1.text ="error";
}
```

And this php code:

```
<?php
    ... some code for the mysql connection and select sentence ...

        $topScores = mysqli_query($con, $topScores);
        $topScores = mysqli_fetch_array($topScores);
        echo "&nickname=$topScores[nickname]&score=$topScores[score]";

?>
```

both runs without errors, the problem is that what i get on flash aren't the variables values but the name of the variables, in other words what i get on vars.nickname is

```
$topScores[nickname]
```

and for vars.score

```
$topScores[score]
```

If i run the php alone i get this:

```
&nickname=jonny&score=100
```

which are the actual variable values i'm trying to get, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may just be loading up the php file as a text file from flash. Can you change the following line:

```
new URLRequest("checkScores.php");
```

to something like:

```
new URLRequest("http://localhost/checkScores.php");
```

or whatever you see in the browser address bar when you "run" it as you said in your question.

Comment: it worked! but i got a new error, Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs. which i fixed changing my php echo sintax to echo "nickname=".urlencode($topScores['nickname'])."&score=".$topScores['score']; Thank you so much!